# File path issues

Tags: file

I have little confusion about file path. whats the difference between /home/shekhar and home/shekhar. My doubt what difference does the addition of an extra "/" at the begning makes

Answer (score 1):

`/` at the start of a path indicates that it's absolute, ie. it starts from the root of the file system. The `/` missing means it's a relative path from what your current directory is.

For example, if you're currently in `/etc`;

`cd /home/shekar` will take you up to the root of the file system and then down to the path `/home/shekar`.

`cd home/shekar` does not go up to the root of the file system and you will end up in `/etc/home/shekar`.

Answer (score 0):

file paths that have a "/" at the front are absolute paths. They start right at the top of the file system

file paths that do not have a / at the front are relative paths. These paths are relative to the current / present working directory (pwd)

Answer (score 0):

Usually on UNIX systems, "/" indicates the root directory. All directories belong to the root directory. To put it in another way, the root directory is the parent directory.

Any directory in your filesystem can be represented by 2 types of pathnames, an "absolute" path name and a "relative" pathname.

An absolute pathname, always starts with the "/" symbol, because every directory belongs to the root directory, and the pathname for any directory or file is from 1 point of reference, i.e root directory.

A relative pathname is relative to the directory that you are currently in. 
For example, 
/home/shekhar is an absolute pathname, whereas home/shekhar is a relative pathname, where your current directory might be the root directory.

Comment: suppose im currently at home and want to locate a file inside shekhar, so will /home/shekhar/filename and home/shekhar/filename both will work.

Comment: if you're already in /home directory, you don't have to write home/shekhar/filename, you can just address the file as shekhar/filename. The absolute path for this will be /home/shekhar/filename as you have mentioned